# Call a java function from a python script

Tags: java, python, list, function, arraylist

I have a Java script - with a function that I wrote, that I send her a list of strings, the function encrypt each element, and returns a list with the encrypted elements.

My problem is this:
I need to use this function in a python script (send a "list" Python object as input, and receive an "ArrayList" Java object).

How can I call a Java function - that I wrote, in a python script?

And does the list objects are consistent between Python and Java (list Vs. ArrayList)?

A big thank you to all!

** Edit: I'm about to use this entire package in AWS Lambda Function **

Comment: Are you using (embedded) Jython or a (standalone) Python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

The main decisions for choosing a solution seem to be

- What do we use to execute the Java program?
- How do we transfer computed data from the Java program to the Python program?

E.g. you could decide to use a Java JVM and execute via a call to the operating system from Python.

The computed data could be sent to standard output (in some suitable format) and read in and processed by Python. (See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760215/2579220) for the os call and i/o)